# How can I use same random background color to fill rectangle in P5js

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, p5.js

I'm trying to do something in P5js. For this, I need to pick random color of an array for background that has to be in `setup`. Then I want to pick this random selected background color to fill rectangle under draw function.

There are other shapes with randomness under background that has to be run once. And there is another object under rectangle that has to be in a loop. That is why one is in `setup` and other one is under the `draw` function. But, I'm going to simplify my problem as:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  colorsPaletteSecond = [color(0, 0, 0),
                         color(160, 57, 164),
                         color(93, 94, 198),
                         color(135, 198, 112), ];            
  let screenColor = random(colorsPaletteSecond);
  background(screenColor);
}

function draw() {
  stroke(0)
  fill(screenColor);
  rect(200,200,100,100);
}
```

I need to define `screenColor` in the `draw` section as well, to get the same color as the background. Any suggestions?

Comment: Move `let screenColor` to the global scope?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had tried it. This time, fill(screenColor) line, it gives an error: [object Arguments]is not a valid color representation.

Comment: Hmm. You'd have to update your post to provide a [mcve]. My suggestion above works fine for me, if you see my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what I did wrong by looking your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move `let screenColor` to the shared scope so that it's accessible from both functions:

```js
let screenColor;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  const colorsPaletteSecond = [
    color(0, 0, 0),
    color(160, 57, 164),
    color(93, 94, 198),
    color(135, 198, 112),
  ];
  screenColor = random(colorsPaletteSecond);
  background(screenColor);
}

function draw() {
  stroke(0);
  fill(screenColor);
  rect(200, 200, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```